# How to paste dates and prevent to be formatted incorrectly?

Tags: excel, date

I need to paste data from an application that contains dates formatted as mm/dd/yyyy. When I past the data into Excel, the dates are identified as dd/mm/yyyy and the dates where the month is incorrectly identified (mm > 12) are turned into text. See example image below

[image]

How can I paste the data to format the dates directly from mm/dd/yyyy to dd/mm/yyyy? I tried to format the columns as date dd/mm/yyyy but it didn't make any difference.

Comment: Can you change your source data?

Comment: No, I have to copy from an application that I can not change the format

Comment: Go to format cells -> Date  and change location to English (U.K). Then, copy the values and select paste values when you are pasting.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should have some paste handle when you paste into excel:

[image]

Select 'Use Text Import Wizard..."

[image]

Select Delimited (Fixed width is fine too, we don't really want to split the information), then next:

[image]

Going with delimited, it's safer to untick everything:

[image]

The last part is the important part. Select Date and pick the format from the source. The source in this case is formatted having the month first, then the date, then the year, so that's what you pick, then you click on finish:

[image]

My local settings have dates in dd/mm/yyyy, so that's what I will get:

[image]

---

If you have multiple columns, you can import them using the appropriate delimiter. When you get to the 3rd part of the wizard, select the column with the date(s) (click on it/them in the preview box) and select the date options.

Comment: Perfect. I resolve it in 2 steps, but this is exactly what I was looking for. Thanks Jerry!!!!

Answer (score 1):

I managed to resolve the issue after copying the data by selecting the data, selecting Data -> Text to Column -> Selecting Date MDY and then formatting the cells as dd\mm\yyyy

Hope this helps to someone else.

Answer (score 0):

Try pre-formatting your excel columns to mm/dd/yyyy first before pasting the data.

Select the cell-range (area) where you're going to paste the data and then right-click > format cells. go to custom and type mm/dd/yyyy and hit Ok.

After that, go ahead and paste the dates.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I found a VBA solution to do that :

```
'Set all the cells in a Text format
ActiveSheet.Cells.NumberFormat = "@"
'Paste data
ActiveSheet.Paste()
'Set all the cells in a Standard format
ActiveSheet.Cells.NumberFormat = "General"
```